# i want to send image and some data using volley in android

Tags: android, android-volley

I want to send image as well as data using volley help me i need simplest way to send it please help me i have tried in postman where i selected the file rather than text and send all went well i need like that.

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("number", strUserName.trim());
            params.put("image", image);
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(params);
                String url = "";
                JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url
                        , json, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
                            String status = object.getString("Status");
                            if (status.equals("200")) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtpVerification.class);
                                intent.putExtra("mobile1",strUserName);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            } else if(status.equals("404")) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter Valid No.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.e("Ashish", " " + e);
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
                mQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
            }
```

I have tried this now but its shopwing me the error my value on addstring are not passing they are sending empty as i am directly putting the value too.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView =  findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    btnChoose =  findViewById(R.id.button_choose);
    btnUpload =  findViewById(R.id.button_upload);

    btnChoose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            imageBrowse();
        }
    });

    btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (filePath != null) {
                imageUpload(filePath);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image not selected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
}

private void imageBrowse() {
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    // Start the Intent
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST) {
            Uri picUri = data.getData();

            filePath = getPath(picUri);

            Log.d("picUri", picUri.toString());
            Log.d("filePath", filePath);

            imageView.setImageURI(picUri);

        }

    }

}

private void imageUpload(final String imagePath) {

    SimpleMultiPartRequest smr1= new SimpleMultiPartRequest(Request.Method.POST, BASE_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("Response", response);
                    try {
                        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        String message = jObj.getString("status");
                        if (message.equals("201")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message + "Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else if (message.equals("200")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message + "Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // JSON error
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


    smr1.addStringParam("a_k_s_no", "1112");
    smr1.addStringParam("year", "2020");
    smr1.addStringParam("month", "01");
    smr1.addStringParam("token", "5c041062bf7ab2a409f910ab34fe6e1e");
    smr1.addFile("fileToUpload", imagePath);
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(smr1);

}

private String getPath(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(getApplicationContext(), contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String result = cursor.getString(column_index);
    cursor.close();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Please add what is the problem you are facing. You need to specify what is the problem which you are facing when you are trying to send data from Android using Volley?

Answer (score 0):

Sample Code :

Volley Image Upload Layout

For creating the above layout you can use the following xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Upload Image using Volley"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_choose"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="Browse Image"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:padding="10dp"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_upload"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="upload"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now lets come to `MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Button btnChoose, btnUpload;
    public static String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.1.100/AndroidUploadImage/upload.php";
    static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    String filePath;
```

Now implement `OnClickListener` interface to our buttons.

```
btnChoose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        imageBrowse();
    }
});
btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (filePath != null) {
            imageUpload(filePath);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image not selected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Now we will create a method to choose image from gallery. Create the following method.

```
private void imageBrowse() {
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    // Start the Intent
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}
```

To complete the image choosing process we need to override the following method.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST){
            Uri picUri = data.getData();
            filePath = getPath(picUri);
            imageView.setImageURI(picUri);
        }
    }
}

// Get Path of selected image
private String getPath(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(getApplicationContext(),    contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String result = cursor.getString(column_index);
    cursor.close();
    return result;
}
```

More information about Android Images, read chapter Amazing Facts of Android ImageView.

Now run your application and if you can choose image from gallery then you can move ahead. In below snapshot you can see mine app is working.Image Upload Using Volley

Now we need to create one more method that will upload the image to our server. Create the following method in `MainActivity` class.

```
private void imageUpload(final String imagePath) {
    SimpleMultiPartRequest smr = new SimpleMultiPartRequest(Request.Method.POST, BASE_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("Response", response);
                    try {
                        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        String message = jObj.getString("message");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // JSON error
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    smr.addFile("image", imagePath);
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(smr);
}
```

So the final complete code for our `MainActivity.java` file would be like

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Button btnChoose, btnUpload;
    public static String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.1.100/AndroidUploadImage/upload.php";
    static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    String filePath;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        btnChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_choose);
        btnUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_upload);
        btnChoose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                imageBrowse();
            }
        });
        btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (filePath != null) {
                    imageUpload(filePath);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image not selected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    private void imageBrowse() {
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        // Start the Intent
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST){
                Uri picUri = data.getData();
                Log.d("picUri", picUri.toString());
                Log.d("filePath", filePath);
                imageView.setImageURI(picUri);
            }
        }
    }
    private void imageUpload(final String imagePath) {
        SimpleMultiPartRequest smr = new SimpleMultiPartRequest(Request.Method.POST, BASE_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.d("Response", response);
                        try {
                            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                            String message = jObj.getString("message");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // JSON error
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        smr.addFile("image", imagePath);
        MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(smr);
    }
    // Get Path of selected image
    private String getPath(Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(getApplicationContext(), contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String result = cursor.getString(column_index);
        cursor.close();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now at last add below permission to your application.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

MyApplication.java

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public static final String TAG = MyApplication.class.getSimpleName();
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static MyApplication mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will work!

Comment: dependency please?

Comment: dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:+'
}

Comment: Error here  MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(smr);

Comment: Okay buddy, I added MyApplication class in answer

Comment: please check answer now